# Whenever cron jobs not working (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, whenever

I am trying to implement cron jobs in my rails app and am completely new to crons. I am using [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem in rails 3.

These are the steps, I have done:

In Gemfile

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

Then ran,

```
wheneverize .
```

And this is how my config/schedule.rb looks like:

```
set :environment, :development

set :path, "/home/pc/Workspace/pep1"


every 1.minutes do
runner "Demo.update_time_slot"
command "rm -rf /tmp/cache"
end
```

My Demo model contains:

```
class << self
def update_time_slot
    .......
end
end
```

On terminal, I ran commands,

```
whenever --update-crontab pep1
whenever -i
```

But it seems like, cron file is not getting executed. But when i execute Demo.update_time_slot on rails console, it works fine.

Output of crontab -l is:

```
            # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: pep1
    * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/pc/Workspace/pep1 && script/rails runner -e development '\''Demo.update_time_slot'\'''

    * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'rm -rf /tmp/cache'

    # End Whenever generated tasks for: pep1

    # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/pc/Workspace/pep1/config/schedule.rb
    * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/pc/Workspace/pep1 && script/rails runner -e development '\''Demo.update_time_slot'\'''

    * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'rm -rf /tmp/cache'

    # End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/pc/Workspace/pep1/config/schedule.rb
```

Output of "grep CRON /var/log/syslog" is:

```
Oct 12 22:37:01 IdeaPad-S400 CRON[10845]: (pc) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'rm -rf /tmp/cache')
Oct 12 22:37:01 IdeaPad-S400 CRON[10846]: (pc) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/mona/Workspace/pep1 && script/rails runner -e development '\''Demo.update_time_slot'\''')
Oct 12 22:37:01 IdeaPad-S400 CRON[10847]: (pc) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/mona/Workspace/pep1 && script/rails runner -e development '\''Demo.update_time_slot'\''')
Oct 12 22:37:01 IdeaPad-S400 CRON[10852]: (pc) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'rm -rf /tmp/cache')
```

I am not getting where things are going wrong. Can anybody help me out in this?

Will really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I added this path in the beginning of schedule.rb:

```
env :PATH, '/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games'
```

Now crons are working perfectly.